# Test dependency not retrieved by `go get`

Tags: go, gitlab

I'm using Golang (1.9 at this time), and using GitLab CI to test and build binaries and Docker containers.

For some projects, I run into this issue (GitLab CI output):

```
$ go get
$ go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint
$ go tool vet -composites=false -shadow=true *.go
$ golint ./...
$ go test --race $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
# gitlab.my.site/core/proj/mypkg mypkg/mypkg_test.go:18:2: cannot find package 
"gitlab.my.site/core/otherproj/otherpkg" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/gitlab.my.site/core/otherproj/otherpkg (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/gitlab.my.site/core/otherproj/otherpkg (from $GOPATH)
FAIL    gitlab.my.site/core/proj/mypkg [setup failed]
```

The `core/otherproj` project is private, but clonable through SSH, which is my current workaround.

My main problem is that private projects in dependencies most often work, but sometimes, `go get`ting them consistently fails.

Worth noting is that the `otherproj/otherpkg` is only a dependency in the test for `proj/mypkg`; not its primary functionality.

**My question is**; why does this specific dependency not download from `go get`, and how do I make it download?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

From the [docs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) (also available via `go get --help`):

> The -t flag instructs get to also download the packages required to build the tests for the specified packages.

So you need to run `go get -t` to download test dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I saw this while researching the issue, but as far as I understood, that flag made sure to recursively download dependencies for the tests of the dependencies (i.e. allowing you to test your deps as well as your own code). I'll try again, though!

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström: Yes, it does that, too.

Comment: I added the flag, changing `go get` to `go get -t`. Unfortunately, the same issue remains.

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström: `go get -t ./...` is probably what you need, if you have recursive deps, too.